Need to export dump only single or multiple index , meilisearch 1.10.2 , self hosteded
I have installed meilisearch version 1.10.2 in ubuntu 22 , I can do take dump and import data to another or same meilisearch server , same or different version . But is that possible to take dump only need index , is that possible ? and how to do that . Thanks
